# Searching the file's directory instead of putting the exact file location

Tags: html

For a programming course we are to create a basic webpage login that redirects to a homepage. (Note: We are not required to create a database.)

The code works but I want to change that by searching the directory of the same folder of the html. The loginwebpage.html is also located in the same directory as index.html. I want it to search only the directory so regardless of where the folder is located it will still find the index.html instead of searching for it in a specific location.

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="file:///C:\Users\n\Downloads\s\our webpage\index.html" id="f1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you are asking because it looks like 2 different questions.  Are you just wanting to redirect to a different webpage or to something else?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. It seems like I have accidentally deleted the line of code that I want to change. 

<form name="f1" method="post" action="file:///C:\Users\Nathaniel\Desktop\Video\our webpage\index.html" id="f1">

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly and what you are doing is a log in page that redirects off of the landing page then what you want to do is something like this. 

Generic page load with everything on the landing page (login page) with certain controls or whatever textbox/drop down list/radio button.  Then wrap it in a try catch block

try 
{
if (textboxUser) and (textboxPassword) = correct
Response.Redirect to what ever page you want
}
catch

Comment: So that means I have to rewrite the line of code that I made? If so, what is the correct one?

Comment: There are a lot of videos of it, its not overly complicated but what you want to do is a response.redirect 

Knowing what to do is half the battle, the other half is figuring out how to do it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Omda1OjR9XQ is an example. 

That single line of code isn't enough to do what you want it to do.  
look here
http://www.sbp-romania.com/Blog/2009/01/27/making-a-response-redirect-from-plain-html-or-javascript.aspx